# C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load c:/php7/php7apache2.dll into server: The specified module could not be found

Tags: php, apache, httpd.conf

I am new apache and php. I installed Apache server in C drive, `C:\Apache24`. then I installed the services in CMD using this command 
`httpd -k install`. then I go to Windows Service. I can start and stop Apache2.4, it is working fine. I want to run php project. Now I installed php in `C:\php7`.

**PHP version:**

```
PHP 7.3.0RC3 (cli) (built: Oct 10 2018 01:23:45) ( NTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x64 ),
Copyright (c) 1997-2018, The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.0-dev, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

Then I open Apache `httpd.conf` file (C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf).

```
PHPIniDir "C:/php7"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
LoadModule php7_module "C:/php7/php7apache2_4.dll"  [this is line no 550]
```

I added the above line in httpd.conf. Then start Apache with this command `httpd -k start` or another I can start it in **Windows Services**.

Thus, I am getting this error. Why I do not know.

```
C:\Apache24\bin>httpd -k start
httpd: Syntax error on line 550 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load c:/php7/php7apache2.dll into server: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: What's on line 550? I doubt HTTPd is randomly changing `C:/php7/php7apache2_4.dll` to `C:/php7/php7apache2.dll` :)

Comment: LoadModule php7_module "C:/php7/php7apache2_4.dll". this line is in 550

Comment: That's definitely in the file `C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf`?

Comment: yeah. it is in C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf

Comment: I'm going to double check. Definitely `C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf` and not e.g. `C:/Apache24/httpd.conf`. If you're absolutely sure, then I have no idea I'm afraid.

Comment: C:\Apache24\conf i am sure. it is inside conf folder in apache.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182403/discussion-between-kumaresan-perumal-and-jon-stirling).

Comment: Yep, no idea then. As far as I'm aware what you're describing can't happen, so will be interesting to see if somebody else has a solution.

Comment: PHP has x64 and x86 versions,  try another if one doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out myself. I installed thread safe version. **Please do not install non thread safe version.**

The thread safe version is VC15 x64 Thread Safe (2018-Oct-10 19:19:47)

I added this line in Apache **httpd.conf** file.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php 
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html 
LoadModule php7_module "c:/php730rc3/php7apache2_4.dll" 
PHPIniDir "c:/php730rc3"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error too, after confirming this module exist in /modules/, I checked the httpd.conf and found that the SRVROOT was wrong.

```
Define SRVROOT "D:/Project/Apache24/bin"   //wrong
Define SRVROOT "D:/Project/Apache24"      //correct
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have access cmd like administrator. I supposed that you have changed also httpd.conf and you have modify ${SRVROOT}.. with C:/localhost ( you must have folder localhost in C). ANd install **thread safe version**